# Square Webhook API Error "Client does not exist"

Tags: webhooks, square-connect

I have enabled webhooks for my application, and am attempting to make the PUT request for the events I am interested in.

The response I get is a 404 with this body:

```
{
  "type": "not_found",
  "message": "Client does not exist"
}
```

I have attempted to issue a GET and the result is the same.
Endpoints I have tried include:

- https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/webhooks
- https://connect.squareup.com/v1/BP0C3P3DS975P/webhooks

All other v1 and v2 API endpoints seem to be working.

The merchant authorized the application with these scopes: MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ PAYMENTS_READ SETTLEMENTS_READ BANK_ACCOUNTS_READ CUSTOMERS_READ ORDERS_READ

I think I've looked through the docs very carefully, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhooks are enabled on a **per-app** basis. Please confirm you have enabled Webhooks for this specific application:
[Webhooks Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBxbI.png)

Also, you should submit API requests to the location-specific endpoint: /v1/{location_id}/webhooks

Comment: I enabled it (and re-enabled it a few more times).  I tried both the location Id from the v2 API and the merchant Id from v1.  I even used the exact same curl request (with my bearer token) in the solution to another stack overflow answer - same result.

Comment: This may have been user error.  I just checked the config on another machine and it wasn't set.  Now that I saved it again it is working.  Thanks for the prompt response.